# Django_seed Seeding Process Inserting Excessive Data and Causing Database Overflow

Tags: django, postgresql, seed

I'm encountering an issue with the seeding process in my Django application using the django_seed library. I've configured the seed data for my TipoSuscripcion model following the documentation and examples provided. However, when I execute the seeding process, it inserts an excessive amount of data into the database, filling it with unwanted records.

Here's a summary of the problem and my setup:
Utilizing the django_seed library for data seeding.
Defined seed data for the TipoSuscripcion model in a separate seed script (seeds.py).
Running the seeding process via the python manage.py seed app command.

this is my code

```
from django_seed import Seed
from app.models import TipoSuscripcion

def seed_data():
    seeder = Seed.seeder()
    tipo_suscripcion_data = [Private]

seeder.add_entity(TipoSuscripcion, tipo_suscripcion_data, custom_fields={'activo': True})  # Assuming 'activo' is a boolean field

    # Execute the seeding
    seeder.execute()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    seed_data()
```

```
This si the file tree
drwxr-xr-x     - emilioramirezmscarua 25 Jan 10:13.     app
.rw-r--r--  131k emilioramirezmscarua 23 Jan 13:16      db.sqlite3
.rwxr-xr-x   686 emilioramirezmscarua 23 Jan 13:16      manage.py
.rw-r--r--  5.9k emilioramirezmscarua 25 Jan 10:13      README
.md.rw-r--r--    45 emilioramirezmscarua 23 Jan 13:16   requirements
.txtdrwxr-xr-x     - emilioramirezmscarua 25 Jan 11:44  seeds
.rw-r--r--  5.7k emilioramirezmscarua 25 Jan 11:40      └── seeds
.pydrwxr-xr-x     - emilioramirezmscarua 24 Jan 11:28   sistema_control_de_inventarios
drwxr-xr-x     - emilioramirezmscarua 23 Jan 13:16      staticfiles
```

I only want a seeds for the table TipoSuscripcion, but it is strange that it give me so much trash in all the tables